# how to call a perl script in makefile and capture its output

Tags: perl, makefile, gnu-make

I have a Perl script and output of that Perl script has to be captured in a makefile.

```
variable: = <path of script>
output: = $(shell $(echo))
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what is it that the scipt computes?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Shell-Function.html),

```
var := $(shell script)
```